Space Race covered by a reality show
This movie is a recent film about a space race to Mars between USA and Russia - its funded in part by a successful billionaire and partly by advertisements for a dumb reality TV show on Earth and overall the movie is very satiric.
It is also a cel-shaded film.  
For some reason, I can't find the title of this film online, does anyone remember what it is called?

Sounds like the animated US comedy Mars from 2010. It's about the space race to Mars that's covered by an MTV-like show, and the film is done in cel-shading. Here's the trailer:



